# spaCy/displacy visualiser paint individual nodes

Tags: python, spacy

While visualising with displacy, I was wondering if it is possible to paint individual nodes in a dependency tree. With the following code:

```
s = 'Und FDP-Luftikus Jürgen W. Möllemann bereist seinerseits schon jetzt eifrig den Nahen Osten , um für diesen Fall gerüstet zu sein und sich als neuer liberaler Außenminister zu empfehlen .'
from pathlib import Path
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('de_core_news_sm')
tree = nlp(s)
od = {'collapse_phrases': True, 'collapse_punct': True}
svg = spacy.displacy.render(tree, style='dep', options=od)
output_path = Path('/share/example_deps.svg')
output_path.open('w', encoding='utf-8').write(svg)
```

I generate the following graph:

[image]

Which is all fine. But now for illustration purposes, I'd like to paint (or alternatively put into italics/bold) individual words or nodes. Does anyone know if this is possible? Can't find anything related to this in the [docs](https://spacy.io/api/top-level#displacy_options)